# Why does USDA require wooden posts when installing fencing with T-posts?

Tags: fence

I've fenced off an area near our house to make an off-leash play area for our dogs.

I used T-posts and 2" x 4" (cell size) net ("utility fabric") from OKBrand.com:

[image: utility fabric]

On the other side of that piece of paper is a link to "installation practices" document from the USDA Natural Resources Conservation Service,
https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/Internet/FSE_DOCUMENTS/nrcs144p2_016391.pdf
which states:

> Steel posts must be new and be painted or galvanized and weigh a minimum of 1.25 pounds per one foot of length. Post will be driven 18” inches in the ground or as specified by manufacturer. Every 50 feet or 4th post will be wooden.

My fence is 50 feet by 30 feet -- and it's 100% T-posts.

I was wondering WHY they say that there should be wooden posts mixed in with the steel ones?

Is there a practical reason to mix in the wooden posts?

Comment: T-posts are weaker and much smaller face/surface against ground/dirt.  USDA deals with 1000 to 2000 plus pounds of animals against a fence.  A T-post does not stand much chance against a 2000 pound bull scratching up against it.

Comment: The T-posts hold the fence up.  The wooden posts provide resistance/bracing to the fence bending over/being bent over.

Comment: Ever try to staple a "No Trespassing" sign to a steel post? If you don't have a contractual relationship with the USDA (e.g. a conservation easement or "pay you not to grow", relax budget hawks, it's a pittance)... then you probably don't need to follow their rules.

Comment: That makes sense.  I see that a wooden post is much bigger (thicker) than a T-post, so it would be stronger.  Thanks!